# Creating two HTML5 video elements with the same source not working

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to do a simple thing but so far I have not had any success and I cannot get why it does not work.

I need two (or several, for that matter) HTML5 video elements to play the same video, but it does not work. Here is the code I have been trying: http://jsfiddle.net/4K8DZ/

Any ideas on why is that?

Thanks

Comment: It's playing the same video now.What was your actual problem be more specific.

Comment: I forgot to point out that I am using Chrome

Comment: There is no problem in your fiddle demo it's playing good and doing it's job pretty well and you're saying that it dosen't work in chrome.I have tested it in chrome and it's playing fine.Are there any specific errors are you getting while runing have you checked in chrome console?

Comment: Your videos are playing simultaneously. Give some time to get them started

Comment: I can confirm that with chrome build 26.0.1450.1 (191000) the videos don't play togehter, only one start and when totally buffered the other one will play.

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this problem myself. I worked around it by adding a query param to the source file of the second video element’s source:

```
video1.setAttribute("src", "whatever.mp4");
video2.setAttribute("src", "whatever.mp4?random=1");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/br2bn/

Comment: restlessdesign, you're a life-saver!

Comment: This is a known bug with Chrome. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31014

Answer (score 0):

Though I am still not able to just comment, I have to submit this as an answer.

This bug continuous for files > 10mb as long as one of them is buffering, the other one wont work. If you press pause, the other one will work.

I updated the example to demonstarate the bug: http://jsfiddle.net/4K8DZ/23/

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I can play only one video with iPad + Safari and Chrome on Windows7.
With Safari, if I start one video, then another stops.
With Chrome, I got almost the same result.