# Html5 video does not work in two tabs

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

Im trying to view 2 html5 videos in my browser (chrome) but im only able to play it in one tab. Is there any solution to this ?
Here is a similar question but it did not give me the proper answer [Creating two HTML5 video elements with the same source not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445748/creating-two-html5-video-elements-with-the-same-source-not-working) .

If you dont understand my question just try to open this link in two tabs, and you will see that the first one plays but the second one doesnt.
http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/aboutmozilla640x360.mp4

Comment: See my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25342607/2105930

This is a known Chrome bug.